# How can I clear faulty error messages in XCode?

Tags: xcode

XCode keeps glitching out on me and listing errors in files that have long since been fixed or deleted.

How can I clear all the errors and get it to start from fresh?

Answer (score 8):

XCode 10.3. On the menu: Product -> Clean Build Folder

Comment: lol.  Thank you.  I'm no longer working on the project, so if anyone else can confirm this works, let me know and I'll mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Yeah, it totally works. Thanks for saving my sanity from an annoying stuck build error.

Comment: Just cleaning didn't help me. Cleaning and restarting XCode did.

Comment: I also had to turn off "Show live issues" --  Xcode -> Preferences -> General -> Show live issues

Comment: So this still issue still occurs on the latest Xcode v14 beta 3.  This solution and a subsequent rebuild did the trick for me. Thanks